# Java Equivalent of c# this.GetType().Namespace

Tags: java, namespaces

Which is the java equivalent of c#

`this.GetType().Namespace`

to get the package name in which the class is contained?

Comment: this.getClass() are you asking about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the package of a class:

```
Package myPackage = getClass().getPackage(); 

// or from a static context:
Package myPackage = MyClass.class.getPackage();
```

as a String:

```
String packageName = getClass().getPackage().getName();

// or from a static context:
String packageName = MyClass.class.getPackage().getName();
```

Comment: yes it works. I was fooled by the different namespave vs package names, i am transitioning to java and i am still somewhat confused on the basics